# Updating multiple entities in google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions

I'm using google appengine with java. I have two Entities: `a` and `b`, where `a` has a list of `b`'s. Now, I want to do the following:

```
try{
 //start transaction
 a1 = getA();
 a2 = getA();
 b1 = new B();
 b2 = new B();
 a1.bs.add(b1);
 a2.bs.add(b2);
 //end trasaction
}catch{
  //rollback
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your transaction, you will have to iterate through your `bs` collections and `put` each object to the datastore.

One thing to keep in mind is that GAE transactions operate on entities in the same entity group.  I would suggest taking a look at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html) if you haven't already done so.